how to send data to the server every n seconds and if they were not delivered then save every m seconds?
I have a Manager class that starts one of several tasks (Poco::Util::TimerTask) that are executed periodically in a separate thread using Poco::Util::Timer. When a certain condition is met, this task should stop and tell the manager to start another task, and so on.
To be more specific, I need to send data to the server every n seconds, and if the data cannot be sent, then save it to a file every m seconds.

Do I need to design it differently? how can I design classes to get rid of the circular dependency (between Manager and tasks)
Maybe do you have ideas how to send and save more simplier?

I can show this at the moment
class Manager {
    Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::TimerTask> sendTask;
    Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::TimerTask> saveTask;
    Poco::Util::Timer timer;
public:
    void start() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(sendTask, 15000, 15000);
    }
 
    void setSendTask() {
         timer.cancel();
         sendTaskPtr_.reset(new SendTimerTask( sender_, saver_, *this, agent_ ));
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(sendTaskPtr_, 0, 15000);
    }
 
    void setSaveTask() {
        timer.cancel();
        saveTaskPtr_.reset(new SaveTimerTask( saver_, sender_, *this, agent_ ));
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(saveTaskPtr_, 0, 20000);
    }
};

class SendTask : public Poco::Util::TimerTask{
public:
    void run() override {
         // sending to server
 
         if (condition) {
             manager.setSaveTask();
         }
    }
private:
     Manager manager;
};


Use std::function<void()> callback objects instead.

molbdnilo, thank you for your comment, please, can you explain in more detail?
